# Multiple requests made by vlcj

Tags: video-streaming, vlcj

I am using vlcj for reading a media file which is located at an URL.

I have some video streaming issues and I have enabled the verbose output for vlcj and the logs look very strange: there are many requests made to the server which is streaming the file (10 for only one file). I noticed that after the first call to backend, the second one si made with a made up "Range" header (or maybe there's a logic but I am missing it). Afterwards, the same request is made again and at some point the "Range" header value is changed and kept at the new value and so on.

The question would if it is normal for vlc to make so many requests and which is the purpose of duplicating requests.

I am also posting here the requests being made.

```
> [1dcb6130] http stream debug: outgoing request:   streaming?id=1011122
> HTTP/1.1
> 
>   Host: hostname.com
> 
>   Accept: */*
> 
>   Accept-Language: en_US
> 
>   User-Agent: VLC/3.0.4 LibVLC/3.0.4
> 
>   Range: bytes=0-
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   [1dcb6130] http stream debug: incoming response:    HTTP/1.1 200 200
> 
>   Date: Tue, 18 Dec 2018 10:35:54 GMT
> 
>   Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_jk/1.2.42
> 
>   Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ASD43SAD123SAD34;path=/;HttpOnly
> 
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
> 
>   Content-Length: 31380626
> 
>   Content-Type: video/mp4
> 
>   [1dcb6130] http stream debug: outgoing request:     GET
> /streaming?id=12345678 HTTP/1.1
> 
>   Host: hostname.com
> 
>   Accept: */*
> 
>   Accept-Language: en_US
> 
>   User-Agent: VLC/3.0.4 LibVLC/3.0.4
> 
>   Cookie: JSESSIONID=ASD43SAD123SAD34
> 
>   Range: bytes=31188554-
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   [1dcb6130] http stream debug: incoming response:    HTTP/1.1 200 200
> 
>   Date: Tue, 18 Dec 2018 10:35:54 GMT
> 
>   Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_jk/1.2.42
> 
>   Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0ASD43SAD123SAD34;path=/;HttpOnly
> 
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
> 
>   Content-Length: 192072
> 
>   Content-Type: video/mp4     [1dcb6130] http stream debug: outgoing
> request:  GET /streaming?id=12345678 HTTP/1.1
> 
>   Host: hostname.com
> 
>   Accept: */*
> 
>   Accept-Language: en_US
> 
>   User-Agent: VLC/3.0.4 LibVLC/3.0.4
> 
>   Cookie: JSESSIONID=0ASD43SAD123SAD34
> 
>   Range: bytes=31188554-
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   [1dcb6130] http stream debug: connection failed     [1dcb6130] http
> stream debug: resolving hostname.com ...  [1dcb6130] http stream
> debug: outgoing request:  GET /streaming?id=12345678 HTTP/1.1
> 
>   Host: hostname.com
> 
>   Accept: */*
> 
>   Accept-Language: en_US
> 
>   User-Agent: VLC/3.0.4 LibVLC/3.0.4
> 
>   Cookie: JSESSIONID=0ASD43SAD123SAD34
> 
>   Range: bytes=31188554-
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   [1dcb6130] http stream debug: incoming response:    HTTP/1.1 200 200
> 
>   Date: Tue, 18 Dec 2018 10:35:55 GMT
> 
>   Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_jk/1.2.42
> 
>   Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ASD43SAD123SAD34;path=/;HttpOnly
> 
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
> 
>   Content-Length: 192072
> 
>   Content-Type: video/mp4
> 
>   [1dcb6130] http stream debug: outgoing request:     GET
> /streaming?id=12345678 HTTP/1.1
> 
>   Host: hostname.com
> 
>   Accept: */*
> 
>   Accept-Language: en_US
> 
>   User-Agent: VLC/3.0.4 LibVLC/3.0.4
> 
>   Cookie: JSESSIONID=ASD43SAD123SAD34
> 
>   Range: bytes=4847078-
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   [1dcb6130] http stream debug: connection failed     [1dcb6130] http
> stream debug: resolving hostname.com ...  [1dcb6130] http stream
> debug: outgoing request:  GET /streaming?id=12345678 HTTP/1.1
> 
>   Host: hostname.com
> 
>   Accept: */*
> 
>   Accept-Language: en_US
> 
>   User-Agent: VLC/3.0.4 LibVLC/3.0.4
> 
>   Cookie: JSESSIONID=ASD43SAD123SAD34
> 
>   Range: bytes=4847078-
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   [1dcb6130] http stream debug: incoming response:    HTTP/1.1 200 200
> 
>   Date: Tue, 18 Dec 2018 10:36:21 GMT
> 
>   Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_jk/1.2.42
> 
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
> 
>   Content-Length: 26533548
> 
>   Content-Type: video/mp4
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   [1dcb6210] prefetch stream error: cannot seek (to offset 4847078)
>   [1dcbd7e8] avi demux warning: failed reading data   [1dcb6130] http
> stream debug: outgoing request:   GET /streaming?id=12345678 HTTP/1.1
> 
>   Host: hostname.com
> 
>   Accept: */*
> 
>   Accept-Language: en_US
> 
>   User-Agent: VLC/3.0.4 LibVLC/3.0.4
> 
>   Cookie: JSESSIONID=ASD43SAD123SAD34
> 
>   Range: bytes=4900374-
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   [1dcb6130] http stream debug: connection failed     [1dcb6130] http
> stream debug: resolving hostname.com ...  [1dcb6130] http stream
> debug: outgoing request:  GET /streaming?id=12345678 HTTP/1.1
> 
>   Host: hostname.com
> 
>   Accept: */*
> 
>   Accept-Language: en_US
> 
>   User-Agent: VLC/3.0.4 LibVLC/3.0.4
> 
>   Cookie: JSESSIONID=ASD43SAD123SAD34
> 
>   Range: bytes=4900374-
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   [1dcb6130] http stream debug: incoming response:    HTTP/1.1 200 200
> 
>   Date: Tue, 18 Dec 2018 10:36:22 GMT
> 
>   Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_jk/1.2.42
> 
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
> 
>   Content-Length: 26480252
> 
>   Content-Type: video/mp4
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   [1dcb6210] prefetch stream error: cannot seek (to offset 4900374)
>   [1dcb6130] http stream debug: outgoing request:     GET
> /streaming?id=12345678 HTTP/1.1
> 
>   Host: hostname.com
> 
>   Accept: */*
> 
>   Accept-Language: en_US
> 
>   User-Agent: VLC/3.0.4 LibVLC/3.0.4
> 
>   Cookie: JSESSIONID=ASD43SAD123SAD34
> 
>   Range: bytes=4847078-
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   [1dcb6130] http stream debug: connection failed     [1dcb6130] http
> stream debug: resolving hostname.com ...  [1dcb6130] http stream
> debug: outgoing request:  GET /streaming?id=12345678 HTTP/1.1
> 
>   Host: hostname.com
> 
>   Accept: */*
> 
>   Accept-Language: en_US
> 
>   User-Agent: VLC/3.0.4 LibVLC/3.0.4
> 
>   Cookie: JSESSIONID=ASD43SAD123SAD34
> 
>   Range: bytes=4847078-
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   [1dcb6130] http stream debug: incoming response:    HTTP/1.1 200 200
> 
>   Date: Tue, 18 Dec 2018 10:36:23 GMT
> 
>   Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_jk/1.2.42
> 
>   Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ASD43SAD123SAD34;path=/;HttpOnly
> 
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
> 
>   Content-Length: 26533548
```

Answer (score 0):

I would venture a guess and say that this has to do with the fact that you are trying to stream a video file over the HTTP protocol.

Since HTTP streaming uses a "playlist" of files to retrieve a video multiple requests will be made when streaming a single video. (You would not like to have to download the complete file before being able to play it, since it would not be "streaming" anymore but playing a locally downloaded file.)

If it is only a single file perhaps it requests a couple of Mb:s per request from the same file to be able to buffer the file instead of downloading it.

Comment: I was expecting the same thing you say ("requesting some more mb in order to build the buffer"), but it is not the case: the requests are not made with incremental values for the _byte_ header, but random values. I have also posted the log file, which I know it is hard to read, but it shows how random are looking those requests.

Comment: Well in that case I would say that it has nothing to do with vlcj since (as far as I know) vlcj is just a wrapper around the VlcLib C library..